# need to find false positive, false negative, true positive from comparing two different ground truth for same image

Tags: python, data-science, pycocotools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUNeY.png)  green is ground truth and the red box is another ground truth An image-1 has one ground truth annotation file and I have drawn a new annotation for it. I need to know whether the new annotations contain all the previous annotations.

I am expecting I want to compare these two ground truths and come up with false positive, false negative, and true positive and sum it up and find out how many, FP, FN and TP in each image

I want results like this image anybody has any idea, I would be very much grateful, thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have rectangle coordinates?  It's pretty easy to do rectangle overlap computations given the coordinates.